# CentOs x86_64 not getting IP in from windows7 machine via data connector, works fine with Office LAN

Tags: networking, virtualbox, centos

Can anyone tell me the required settings to establish connection? I need to establish a connection with another VM too, so the network is set as a Bridged adapter.

This is the output of `ifconfig`:

[image: ifconfig result]

Running `ping 8.8.8.8` results in `Network is unreachable` error.

Comment: What's the network setting on virtualbox? Host only? NAT?

Comment: @journeyman :-It's bridged adapter is selected